Is LUKS disk access disabled during hibernation or sleep?
When a system with LUKS encryption sleeps or goes into hibernation is disk access disabled, requiring the passwords to enable access to the disks when the system is restored?
I would assume that even the hibernation data stored on the disk would be encrypted.
Does LUKS also apply to swap partitions?

Please note that posts on Superuser should contain a single question. Currently, your question has 2 questions and a guessing statement that is asking to be corrected or confirmed. Please EDIT your post to focus on a single question to hold to the rules of the site.


No, LUKS will not require encryption password on wake from sleep/suspend state

Yes, the hibernation data is encrypted if the partition it gets saved to is encrypted

Yes, you can set up your swap partition inside of a LUKS container


